# convert RE to NFA

Tags: finite-automata, regular-expressions

The Regular Expression i am having trouble with is the following  a(b|bcc*)*c. My main concern is what do i do with the c*? I can lay the rest of the diagram correctly (i think) but that part is beyond me. Any help would be great, thank you. What i have: [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your NFA does not recognize $abcc \in L$. To fix it you need to make $2$ non-final and then either:

- Change the label of edge $(5,2)$ from $c$ to $\varepsilon$; or
- Delete vertex $5$. Add the edges $(4,4)$ and  $(4,2)$ with label $c$.

Comment: I tried your first suggestion before and didnt work. Second one doesnt work either though it makes sense to me. Not sure where the problem is

Comment: Can you provide a word that is accepted (resp. is not accepted) by the modified NFA but is not in (resp. is in) the language?

Comment: I see now that for some reason you made $2$ a final state. This is obviously wrong since the NFA accepts $a \not\in L$. To fix this you need to make $2$ non-final in addition to the modification I described in the answer,

Comment: You are completely right, that was the problem. Its accepted now, thanks a ton for your help and time

Answer (score 0):

I simplified your NFA and I got this DFA:

> [image]

Comment: Interesting how this works (havent been that far yet into the course). Tried your last NFA but it gets an error: Incorrect definition of 'a(b|bcc*)*c'. Could be because the exercise asks to give an epsilon-NFA that recognizes the same language?

Comment: Sorry I did a mistake. [bc]* means that the input can also start with "c" and in your case it has to start with "b".